# NSXMLParser inside NSOperation

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser, nsoperation

I have to download and parse huge XML files. Downloading the data occurs in an NSOperation which also triggers the NSXMLParser once the download finishes.

Now since I want to give the user the ability to cancel the whole process at anytime, I added a cancel button, which stops the download and cancels the operation.

Now my problem is: Even though my NSOperation runs in the background, the UI gets completely blocked when the NSXMLParser starts parsing. So touching the cancel button is pointless.

How can this happen? Since I am triggering the parser from inside the NSOperation (after finishing the download) I thought parsing should also be performed in the background?!

**!!!EDIT!!!**: I did a test. I checked the thread the parser runs on. It is the main thread. How can this happen? The NSOperation is started on a background thread, how can the parser be on the main thread? And how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that NSURLConnection apparently calls its delegate on the main thread, resulting in every following method call to be performed also on the main thread.

So I just had to explicitly take my method call in to the background again.

Comment: Select his as the answer as soon as you can

Comment: I'd love to, but I have to wait for 2 days ;)